# How to change emojis available in Slack action menu?

Tags: slack, emoji

In my Slack workspace, when I hover over a message, an action menu appears, which includes three preset emojis which are available for quick access (checkmark, eyes, hands):

[image]

However, I don't use those three emojis very often and would like to replace them with other emojis. How can I do that?

Bonus points if you also know how to change the default "Handy Reactions" shown in the full emoji menu:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to File menu > Preferences > Messages & media tab > Emoji section > "Show one-click reactions on messages"